# If condition with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want if the conditions are true if `df[df["tg"] > 10` and `df[df["tg"] < 32` then multiply by five otherwise divide by two. However, I get the following error

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```py
d = {'year': [2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
     'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,],
     'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'tg': [10, 11, 12, 13, 50, 21, -1, 23],
     'rain': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)


[OUT]

   year  day  month  tg  rain
0  2001    1      1  10     1
1  2001    2      1  11     2
2  2001    3      1  12     3
3  2001    4      1  13     2
4  2001    1      2  50     4
5  2001    2      2  21     1
6  2001    3      2  -1     2
7  2001    4      2  23     1

df["score"] = (df["tg"] * 5) if ((df[df["tg"] > 10]) and (df[df["tg"] < 32])) else (df["tg"] / 2) 

[OUT]
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What I want

```py
   year  day  month  tg  rain   score
0  2001    1      1  10     1    5
1  2001    2      1  11     2    55
2  2001    3      1  12     3    60
3  2001    4      1  13     2    65
4  2001    1      2  50     4    25
5  2001    2      2  21     1    42
6  2001    3      2  -1     2    0.5
7  2001    4      2  23     1    46
```

Comment: You are looking for `where`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

Comment: Although not the most efficient solution, it is also worth being aware of `map` to apply a scalar function to each element: `df["score"] = df["tg"].map(lambda x: x*5 if 10<x<32 else x/2)`

Comment: Your expected output seems wrong for indices 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `where`:

```py
df['score'] = (df['tg']*5).where(df['tg'].between(10, 32), df['tg']/5)
```

Comment: Very minor but just helping OP match their expected output. I had the same idea btw =D

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.where`:

```
# do you need `inclusive=True`? Expected output says yes, your logic says no
mask = df['tg'].between(10,32, inclusive=False)
df['score'] = df['tg'] * np.where(mask, 5, 1/2)

 # or
 # df['score'] = np.where(mask, df['tg'] * 5, df['tg']/2)
```

Output:

```
   year  day  month  tg  rain  score
0  2001    1      1  10     1    5.0
1  2001    2      1  11     2   55.0
2  2001    3      1  12     3   60.0
3  2001    4      1  13     2   65.0
4  2001    1      2  50     4   25.0
5  2001    2      2  21     1  105.0
6  2001    3      2  -1     2   -0.5
7  2001    4      2  23     1  115.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Let try to fix it with for loop

```
[x * 5 if (x > 10 and x < 32) else (x / 2) for x in df['tg']]
Out[64]: [5.0, 55, 60, 65, 25.0, 105, -0.5, 115]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.loc`

```
mask = (df["tg"] > 10) & (df["tg"] < 32)
df.loc[mask, "score"] = df["tg"] * 5
df.loc[~mask, "score"] = df["tg"] / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more detailed explanation of your error message, have a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) from the pandas' docs.

Another option, in addition to the already excellent answers, is the [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which could be a helpful abstraction, especially for multiple conditions, or you probably need to preserve Pandas extension dtypes:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.case_when(
      df.tg.gt(10) & df.tg.le(32), # condition
      df.tg.mul(5), # result if True
      df.tg.div(2), # result if False
      column_name='score')
 
   year  day  month  tg  rain  score
0  2001    1      1  10     1    5.0
1  2001    2      1  11     2   55.0
2  2001    3      1  12     3   60.0
3  2001    4      1  13     2   65.0
4  2001    1      2  50     4   25.0
5  2001    2      2  21     1  105.0
6  2001    3      2  -1     2   -0.5
7  2001    4      2  23     1  115.0
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/examples/notebooks/case_when.ipynb)